Is the std::atexit function does not work in the MSVC compiler?
I want to run a function with parameters and a return value of void when exiting the program. I use the following code to implement it:
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
void Exit(string s){
    ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("E:\\code\\file.txt",ios::out);
    ofs << s << endl;
    ofs.close();
}
int main(){
    auto callback = std::bind(Exit, "test");
    static std::function<void()> atExitCallback = callback;
    atexit([] { atExitCallback(); });
    while(1){
        cout << "running..." << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

When the program exits, it will create a file in the path I specified and write the specified content. When I use g++ to generate executable programs, the program is able to create files when exiting. But when I use MSVC to generate executable programs, the program is not able to create files when exiting. I think the std::atexit function is not working in the MSVC compiler.
My g++ version is 11.2.0,MSVC version is 19.37.32825
Is there a way to make my code work in the MSVC compiler, that is, to get the same result as the g++ compiler when the program exits

Your program has an infinite loop (while(1){ /*...*/ }). When do you think it should exit ? If I remove this loop, I do get a breakpoint hit in Exit after pressing any key (require to release system("pause");).

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? .

IIRC programs with infinite loops are UB in any case.

From cppreference 'Registers the function pointed to by func to be called on normal program termination (via std::exit() or returning from the main function)'. I don't know how you are terminating your program currently, but the way to make it work is to replace that with a normal program termination.

The first three lines of code should all NOT be necessary. Use #include <iostream> for std::cout. use #include <thread> and #include <chorno> and replace sleepwithstd::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));. Calls to system` should be avoided too. All in all it looks like you're not learning C++ from a very good source. Where are you learning it from?

Sorry, my description is not accurate enough. What I want to say is that the atexit function can be triggered when I manually exit the program. I need infinite loops in the program to implement my functionality.

From the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/atexit?view=msvc-170,
The atexit function is passed the address of a function func to be called when the program terminates normally.
To trigger a function when the terminal exits, use SetConsoleCtrlHandler instead of atexit.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <functional>

void Exit(std::string s) {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("E:\\code\\file.txt", std::ios::out);
    ofs << s << std::endl;
    ofs.close();
}

std::function<void()> atExitCallback;

BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD signal) {
    if (signal == CTRL_C_EVENT || signal == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT || signal == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT) {
        if (atExitCallback) {
            atExitCallback();
            exit(1);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main() {
    auto callback = std::bind(Exit, "test");
    atExitCallback = callback;

   
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleHandler, TRUE)) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not set control handler." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "running..." << std::endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }

    return 0;
}

